# Group by, min max, average times

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted some data from SAP. What I want is the average time taken by a resource to perform a task. This is what I have so far:

Input

```
data = wt[(wt['Whse Proc. Type'] == "OPG1") & (wt['Warehouse Task Status'] == "C") ]


result = data.groupby(by = ['Resource', 'Reference'])['Confirmation Time'].agg(['max','min'])
result['diff'] = result['max']-result['min']
display(result)
```

I want to get the average time that each resource takes on and order. But there is a caveat to some data. Some orders have multiple resources working on an order and I want to exclude this data.

Output Receiving

```
Resource       Reference                max               min
Forklift01    80000035640   2018-10-16 21:54:57 2018-10-16 21:16:36 
diff
00:38:21
```

Outptut Wanted (roughly)

```
**Resource**   **Average time spent per order**
Forklift01               30:00:00
```

This needs to be put into data frame with needed exclusions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ? With some data, and your expected output?

Comment: Output expected added. The output currently obtained does not include the exclusion wanted

Comment: It is still hard to understand your question, @megamind. Can you also post an example if input data, so we can see your logic by analyzing the input and output ?

Comment: Added @RafaelC. Let me know if this helps